# how to check if file's 2nd column is sorted

Tags: sorting, unix

I have file

```
chr1    10      20
chr1    30      40
chr1    50      100
chr1    110     130
chr1    200     240
chr1    1000    2000
```

I can use

```
sort -c a.txt
```

but it returns me

```
sort: a:4: disorder: chr1       110     130
```

which makes sense as its not checking if the sorting is done numerically. How can i check if the file is sorted by 2nd column in numerically, like the above file is already sorted? I was looking for a quick, efficient and one liner. My original file may have millions of line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
cut -f2 a |sort -cn
```

I would get the second column and just use -c and -n to check